# SublimeText 2 ObjC symbol (method signature filter)

Tags: objective-c, editor, symbols, sublimetext2

I'm trying to use SublimeText2 as my editor for developing iOS app (expect IB & Coredata). I was not able to get a plugin or way to list the symbol in objc style format. For eg.

```
- (void)unlockWasUnsuccessful:(int)falseEntryCode afterAttemptNumber:(int)attemptNumber
```

symbol should be `unlockWasUnsuccessful:afterAttemptNumber:` but it display them as two line. Here is the image comparing the ST2 symbol list with chocolat.

[image: Goto Symbol CMD+R]

Let me know if there is a way/plugin to list the symbol in correct way.